# How to save the value of a radio button to mysql database using android studio?

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to create a voting application where by there are different posts where for there are two posts with two contastants each. I want when I select one person it records to the database. [Part of the disgn of the posts with its contestants]
Here is part of the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/chairman"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:id="@+id/Chairman">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/duncan_sirikwa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_weight="1.23" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/kosgei_kevin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered taking an OnClickListener?

```
RadioButton radioButton;
radioButton = (radioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
string choice = (String)radioButton.getText();
```

then for your database handler try doing something like this

```
contentValues.put(table_name, choice);
```

since you didn't share any of the java codes this is all I could help with.

I suggest implementing a structure and a SQLiteDatabaseHelper.

Comment: Thanks kaze. The problem is that I haven't written the .java codes  since I don't understand that part really well.

Comment: I suggest looking for examples on google. I have found that looking at examples and finding ways to incorporate the logic and codes of those examples into my own program was very helpful when i was just beginning to learn programming.

Comment: Now if I may ask Kaze Notus when I post the java code would it really help on figuring out this problem

Comment: @Dunn Oh. I have already solved this dilemma. Turns out I was trying to solve the problem I had in a totally wrong way. I should remove this question. :)

Comment: @Dunn Im so sorry. I thought it was my old question. Yes. Posting your code helps me and others figure out how you are trying to save and solve your problem.